# MudBlazor: how to return parameter to a caller?

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I have a MudDialog which get input parameters. It works fine.
How can I return values from the dialog?
I.e. output parameter etc.
For example it sets string inside and I'd like to get after call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok(...))` on the `MudDialogInstance` cascading parameter to return a value back to the caller.

A quick demo:

### InputDialog.razor

```cs
<MudDialog>
  <TitleContent>
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Enter some text</MudText>
  </TitleContent>
  <DialogContent>
    <MudTextField T="string" @bind-Value="@this.input" Immediate="@true"/>
  </DialogContent>

  <DialogActions>
    <MudButton
      Disabled="@string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.input)"
      OnClick="@this.OK"
      Size="@Size.Small">
      OK
    </MudButton>
  </DialogActions>
</MudDialog>

@code {
  private string input = string.Empty;

  [CascadingParameter]
  private MudDialogInstance MudDialog { get; set; } = default!;

  private void OK() => this.MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok(this.input));
}
```

Use it like this:

### Main.razor

```cs
<MudGrid>
  <MudItem sm="12">
    <MudButton OnClick="@this.Prompt" Color="Color.Default">Prompt</MudButton>
    <MudText>Input: @this.input</MudText>
  </MudItem>
</MudGrid>

@code {
  private string input = string.Empty;

  [Inject]
  private IDialogService DialogService { get; set; } = default!;

  private async Task Prompt()
  {
    var options = new DialogOptions
    {
      CloseButton = true,
      DisableBackdropClick = false,
      MaxWidth = MaxWidth.Small
    };

    var result = await this.DialogService.Show<InputDialog>(string.Empty, new DialogParameters(), options).Result;
    this.input = result.Data as string ?? string.Empty;
  }
}
```

Test it here: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wOwRuQvUyTIflERS